# Moving selected objects to existing colection with Python

Tags: python, collections

Literally, none of the threads I searched answer my question.

I need to move multiple objects to newly made Collection named "REFLECTIONS".
But once I do this I want to all of the upcoming objects to move into same "REFLECTIONS" Collection, and not creating new one "REFLECTIONS.001"

```
  import bpy

C = bpy.context

# List of object references
objs = C.selected_objects

# Set target collection to a known collection 
coll_target = C.scene.collection.children.get("REFLECTIONS")

# Set target collection based on the collection in context (selected) 
#coll_target = C.collection

# If target found and object list not empty
if coll_target and objs:

    # Loop through all objects
    for ob in objs:
        # Loop through all collections the obj is linked to
        for coll in ob.users_collection:
            # Unlink the object
            coll.objects.unlink(ob)

        # Link each object to the target collection
        coll_target.objects.link(ob)
```

This DOES NOT DO THE TRICK

Answer (score 0):

##### A function to move an object to a collection

```
import bpy

def move_object_to_collection(obj, coll):
    old_colls = [c for c in obj.users_collection]
    coll.objects.link(obj)
    for c in old_colls:
        c.objects.unlink(obj)

# move_object_to_collection(
#     bpy.data.objects["Light"],
#     bpy.data.collections["Collection 2"]
# )
```

##### Moving selected objects to collection

```
coll = bpy.data.collections["Collection 2"]
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    move_object_to_collection(obj, coll)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't make this to work..